# Gaussian Process Regressor scikit learn does not recognise 'eval_MSE=True'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, prediction, gaussian-process

I am using Gaussian Process Regressor scikit learn to predit data for the models. While using gp, I also need to find uncertainity in each value present in the dataset. The documentation suggests to use "gp.predict(self, X, eval_MSE=True)". I used the same 'eval_MSE' in the code available online to test, but it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: predict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eval_MSE'
```

The code I used for testing:

```
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(corr='squared_exponential', theta0=1e-1,
                     thetaL=1e-3, thetaU=1,
                     nugget=(dy / y) ** 2,
                     random_start=100)

gp.fit(X, y)

y_pred, MSE = gp.predict(x, eval_MSE=True)

sigma = np.sqrt(MSE)
```

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @jimi, great question, I have the same problem, could you find a solution yet, apart from downgrading?

Answer (score 2):

Either go back to previous version of scikitlearn: [GaussianProcess.predict](https://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess.predict)
... or you adapt to the newest: [GaussianProcessClassifier.predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.predict)

Not only the `predict` arguments has changed, but the name of the classifier itself, the input arguments, etc.

Summary from previous links:

- Old GaussianProcess (version 0.17):

  class sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess(regr='constant', corr='squared_exponential', beta0=None, storage_mode='full', verbose=False, theta0=0.1, thetaL=None, thetaU=None, optimizer='fmin_cobyla', random_start=1, normalize=True, nugget=2.2204460492503131e-15, random_state=None)

  predict(X, eval_MSE=False, batch_size=None)
- New GaussianProcessClassifier:

  class sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier(kernel=None, *, optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b', n_restarts_optimizer=0, max_iter_predict=100, warm_start=False, copy_X_train=True, random_state=None, multi_class='one_vs_rest', n_jobs=None)

  predict(X)

Comment: Would be nice if someone more familiar with these variables, make a **input variable table match** from 0.17 to newest version please. For example, how to set `eval_MSE` from now on.

Comment: Garcia Hi, thanks for your answer, I have the same problem, do you happen to know how to deal with `eval_MSE` in the current version?